# Sqoop import split by column and different database to split that data

Tags: sqoop

I have a requirement. 
I need to get data from Teradata database **a** into Hadoop.
I have access to only view in that database and need to pull data from that view. As I don't have read/write access to that database. I cannot use --split-by column option in my sqoop import query.
So is there a option where I can say sqoop to use database **b** for storing the split data and then move the data into Hadoop

Query:

```
sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://xx.aa.dd.aa;databaseName=a" \
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager \
--username XXXX \
--password XXXX \
--num-mappers 20 \
--query "select * from (select ID,name,x,y,z from TABLE1 where DT between '2018/01/01' and '2018/01/31') as temp_table where updt_date <'2018/01/31' AND \$CONDITIONS" \
--split-by id \
--target-dir /user/XXXX/sqoop_import/XYZ/2018/TABLE1
```

Comment: What the exception are you getting when executing this command

Comment: It says I have only view access and not write access when I use split by on the main table. So looking for other options. For sqoop export I can use a staging table, but is there any option in sqoop import where I can give an option of different database where it can create staging tables?